# angularjs - problems creating a custom text editor using Divs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a text editor that uses divs for the content instead of iframes but when i for instance click the 'H1' button to change the look of the text, the text i have selected gets deselected, making it impossible for me to update the view of the content. I have my html setup like this below

```
<a ng-click="parseHeader()">H1</a>
<div contenteditable="true" ng-model="divContent" ng-bind-html="divContent"></div>
```

(Not sure how i should do the controller since i cant get a proper selection working for div content, I would use textarea but i want the html to be rendered on update)

I tried creating a ng-bind-html kind of solution before this but the html doesnt update as i type into the div, and I'm avoiding iframes and the execCommand because the execCommand doesnt allow for class/id's to be added and so on. Is there a way i can create a successful WYSIWYG Editor using Divs and have it work how it's supposed to?????

Comment: TextAngular may do what you want out of the box http://textangular.com/. It uses Rangy behind the scenes so if you want to build an editor from scratch you may want to start there https://github.com/timdown/rangy

Comment: check out http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html

Comment: The [AngularJS ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) has an example of creating a contenteditable div.